# SonarQube throws CodeSmell "Add the missing @deprecated Javadoc tag."

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube

I use Java 8 and the existing code just had @Deprecated and it was tagged by SonarQube. I tried adding @deprecated Javadoc tag to fix this issue. But, it still throws the same error. Here's what I have added:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
/**
 * @deprecated (Not using this now)
 */
@Deprecated
public class SomeClass {
```

Can someone please point out what the mistake is in the above code? Or, provide me the correct way to solve this issue.

Comment: Add `since` and/or `forRemoval` arguments to the `@Deprecated` anotation. Example `@Deprecated(since="4.2", forRemoval=true)`

Comment: Could you try the suggestion in my answer and let me know if it works?

Comment: @Eritrean - "since" and "forRemoval" are required for java >= 9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/**
 * @deprecated (when, why, refactoring advice...)
 */
@Deprecated
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SomeClass {

}
```

For more information: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1123

Comment: Moving the javadoc and the @Depcreted to the top did the trick. Thanks!